# Route does not render component on 2nd level of children

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

In App.js

```
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
      <Route path="/signout" component={SignOut} />
      <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
      <Redirect to="/" />
    </Switch>
```

In Dashboard.js

```
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/students' component={ManageStudents} />
        <Route path='/lecturers' component={ManageLecturers} />
        <Route path='/surveys' component={ManageSurveys} />
      </Switch>
```

In ManageStudents.js

```
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/students/upload' component={UploadFileArea}/>
    </Switch>
```

I can access /signout in Dashboard but in ManageStudents when I click signout the url is http://localhost:3000/students/signout but i doesn't render Signout component. Add `<Route path="/students/signout" component={SignOut} />` and it can render. 
Can anyone explain why does it happen and solution without adding an additional route?

Comment: Can you share how you're building your link to "signout"?

Comment: @Davo oh, I just found out I'm retarded when setup the NavLink for signout. I use to='signout' instead of '/signout'. It's fine now. Thank you for poiting out the root of my stupidity

Comment: Haha, no problem! Stuff like that happens all the time man. I still think your question is valuable. I just added the answer while you replied to the comment so others may find it useful ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get redirected to `http://localhost:3000/students/signout` there's actually no route that resolves to `SignOut` component under that URL pattern (that's why it fails):

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
  <Route path="/signout" component={SignOut} />
  <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
  <Redirect to="/" />
</Switch>
```

However, you don't need to add the route to cover that scenario (your routes look fine). I most likely need to update the way you're building your the link that points to "signout".